# how to compare values in unequal zip list in django?

Tags: python, django

I have two unequal lists and I have zipped it and passed it as a context from my view.In my template, I have a multi select drop down where I want to compare the values and show selected there on the dropdown.But i am unable to achive that.
here is my code:-
first list:-

```
university_all_list = Universities.objects.using('cms').all()
```

second list:-

```
university_ids_list = []
school_university_mapping = SchoolAdminUniversityMappings.objects.filter(userId=cms_user)
for university_ids in school_university_mapping:
        university_ids_list.append(university_ids.universityId)
print university_ids_list
```

combing the two list:-

```
zip_list = zip(university_all_list, cycle(university_ids_list)) if len(university_all_list) > len(
        university_ids_list) else zip(cycle(university_all_list), university_ids_list)
```

now,using that zip_list in template:-

```
<div class="col-sm-8 multiselect_container">
                                        <select class="mutisel" id="first_select" multiple="multiple"
                                                value="university_all_list.id"
                                                name="universityId"
                                                id="userName" required>


                                            {% for university,id in zip_list %}

                                                    {% if id == university.id %}

                                                        <option value="{{ university.id }}"
                                                                selected>{{ university.name }}</option>
                                                    {% else %}
                                                        <option value="{{ university.id }}"
                                                        >{{ university.name }}</option>
                                                    {% endif %}

                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </select>
                                        <script>
                                            $("select.mutisel").multipleSelect({
                                                filter: true,
                                                placeholder: "Select",
                                            });
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
```

but there isnt any dropdown selected in multiselect.

Comment: yaa sry forgot that my bad.....

Comment: No worries. All the best with your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with lists of inequal length you should use itertool [izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>   If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in
>   with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is
>   exhausted.

As suggested in the docs, you need to set a default value for the missing entries.

Having said that it's most unusual to need to use zip or izip_longest with database records. This sort of this can easily be handled at database levels using joins which are fully supported by the Django ORM. What is the relationship between `Universities` and `SchoolAdminUniversityMappings`? Have you declared it explicitly?

Comment: I have some values from `Universities` stored in  `SchoolAdminUniversityMappings` and I wanted to check which values are stored in `SchoolAdminUniversityMappings` which belong to the `Universities`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `ForeignKey`?

Comment: No both tables are at a different database and I am storing the id of `Universities` into an array and then inserting into `SchoolAdminUniversityMappings` and when I am comparing I also doing it the same way storing it into an array and then comparing.So I cant user foreign key.